# What is the A Record configuration for redirecting email services to one IP address, and redirecting http request to another IP address?

Tags: dns, cpanel, cname, a-records

I have a hosting account with hostproviderexample.

I have a domain exampledomain.com that needs to be redirected to this hosting account at hostproviderexample.

However, I only need the redirection on the http or the website request. The email request is already pointing to another IP address of my email server.

How can I do this with exampledomain.com's DNS record? What A Record and CNAME record should I add?

Thank you in advance for the help,

Answer (score 0):

You will have to setup the "A" record of your domain to hosting provider IP. You have already setup your MX record to mail server so there is no need to change anything, Just change your domain "A" record to hosting server IP.